# Neo4j lucene search with java/scala API

Tags: java, scala, lucene, search-engine, neo4j

Am working on a website where I need to store all the articles written by the users. Whenever a particular user enters a key word I need to search for the articles related to that keyword. Right now am indexing the article content of all the articles using Neo4j Lucene index like below

```
ArticleContentIndex += (article_node,"article_data",a_data)
```

and searching for the articles based on the keyword like below

```
val article_content_index = getNodeIndex("article_content").get
val w = "*"+word+"*"
val articles = article_content_index.query("article_data",w).iterator()
```

This approach is taking more time as the number of articles increase. Is there any better approach to do this?

EDIT: It'a actually taking more time to search whenever the search keyword consists most common words like "the", "is", "a" and etc

Answer (score 3):

I didn't try to use Neo4j with lucene, but as an alternative you can use RAMDirectory.

```
val analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43)
val index = new RAMDirectory()
val config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_43, analyzer)
```

Then on Lucene launch you can add your data to the index:

```
mkIndex(xs: Iterable[Articles])
```

Index contains documents:

```
def mkIndex(xs: Iterable[Articles]) {
  def withWriter[T](f: IndexWriter => T): T = {
    val iw = new IndexWriter(index, config)
    Try(f(iw)) match {
      case Success(_) => iw.close()
      case Failure(e) => // do something with exception
  }

  withWriter { _.addDocuments(xs.map(mkDoc)) }
}
```

so we need to make a document:

```
def mkDoc(art: Article): Document = make(new Document) { doc =>
  doc add TextField("id", art.id.toString)
  doc add TextField("data", art.content)
  doc add TextField("author", art.author)
}
```

So when index is ready you need a search function:

```
/**
 * id - your article ID,
 * field - the default field for query terms
 * lim - limit results
 */ 
def search(id: String, field: String, lim: Int): Seq[Article] = {
    val reader = DirectoryReader.open(index)
    val searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader)
    val collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(lim, true)

    val q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43, field, analyzer).parse(id)
    searcher.search(q, collector)
    val hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs
    val results = hits map { hit => searcher doc hit.doc }
    reader.close()

    results map { doc => Article(doc.get("id"), doc.get("data"), doc.get("author")) }
  }
```

With this search function you can make fuzzy search or wildcard search.

That's not a direct answer for best practice on using Neo4j, but an alternative view. It compeletes fuzzy seach in 50k documents in less then a second on small AWS machine.